# How to interpret &gt and &lt in a xml file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i came across a xml file entry which looks like this "closed><true" . Does this mean closed 'not equal to' true? What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Do you have a bit more context? It's kind of hard to tell based on only that information.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, The full condition i see in a product is  result="closed&gt;&lt;true and event.end&gt;tod()

Comment: Can you add the chunk of XSLT you are looking at? We need more context.